# Active Directory Helper Class

Tags: .net, active-directory, helper

Is there a Active Directory Helper Class available somewhere? Just checking before I re-invent the wheel.

I need to

1. Validate a user in AD.
2. Get hhis/her member roles.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In .NET 3.5, you want to look in [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx).  For earlier, versions [System.DirectoryServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) has what you need, but it's a little more work.

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Domain ))
{
      var valid = context.ValidateCredentials( username, password );
      using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity( context,
                                                      IdentityType.SamAccountName,
                                                      username ))
      {
          var groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
      }
}
```

Comment: I am developing on a laptop not part of the domain. Can I pass such request to AD?

Comment: If your users are local to the machine, you can use ContextType.Machine instead of ContextType.Domain to focus your queries against the local authorization store.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some example code that I have been using:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

public static string GetProperty(SearchResult searchResult, 
    string PropertyName)
{
    if (searchResult.Properties.Contains(PropertyName))
        return searchResult.Properties[PropertyName][0].ToString();
    else
        return string.Empty;
}

public MyCustomADRecord Login(string UserName, string Password)
{
    string adPath = "LDAP://www.YourCompany.com/DC=YourCompany,DC=Com";

    DirectorySearcher mySearcher;
    SearchResult resEnt;

    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(adPath, UserName, Password, 
        AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
    mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(de);

    string adFilter = "(sAMAccountName=" + UserName + ")";
    mySearcher.Filter = adFilter;

    resEnt = mySearcher.FindOne();


    return new MyCustomADRecord()
    {
        UserName = GetProperty(resEnt, "sAMAccountName"),
        GUID = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry().NativeGuid.ToString(),
        DisplayName = GetProperty(resEnt, "displayName"),
        FirstName = GetProperty(resEnt, "givenName"),
        MiddleName = GetProperty(resEnt, "initials"),
        LastName = GetProperty(resEnt, "sn"),
        Company = GetProperty(resEnt, "company"),
        JobTitle = GetProperty(resEnt, "title"),
        Email = GetProperty(resEnt, "mail"),
        Phone = GetProperty(resEnt, "telephoneNumber"),
        ExtensionAttribute1 = GetProperty(resEnt, "extensionAttribute1")
    };
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you sharing this.

Answer (score 2):

System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory namespace

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.aspx

Comment: This is really for interacting with and managing administrative aspects of ActiveDirectory -- schema, servers, sites, forests, etc.  The user-related components are in a different namespace.